# How to duplicate material when duplicating an object?

Tags: materials, image-sequence

I import a sequence of images as an animated plane.

I want to have multiple objects using the same animated sequence, but for a bit of variety, I want each of them to start at a different frame of my animated sequence (this can be done in the shader editor by changing the `Start Frame` of the image sequence input).

First, I import my images sequence as an animated plane:

1. *File > Import > Images as Planes*
2. Select my images sequence (`01.png`, `02.png`, etc.)
3. In *Import options*, select *Animate Image Sequences*.

This creates a plane with my image sequence, animated.

I make the animation cyclic by selecting *Cyclic* in the shader editor for the image input.

My problem now: If I duplicate the object, everything is duplicated **except the material.** (as stated in the manual)

[image: Screenshot showing the two duplicated objects with the same material in Blender scene collection]

How do I create a separate material, which is an independent copy of the first?

I tried to re-import the same data, but Blender is apparently too smart and still links my new object to the existing material. I even tried to copy-paste my image sequence to another directory, but somehow Blender is still able to realize it's the same data, and re-use the same material!

Comment: In the Preferences > Editing > Objects > Copy on Duplicate > enable Material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Preferences > Editing > Objects > Copy on Duplicate* > enable *Material*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It solved the material problem, but the animation is still synced, even if I change the "Start Frame" of the other material... I guess it's another problem so I'll post another question :)